# Changing histogram x-axis scale

Tags: r, histogram

I have a vector of small p-values.

```
pvalues=c(0.8793444,0.8793444,1.1372108,1.6548777,1.5721364,5.1473193,
          0.6535714,0.2611629,1.5300548)
```

I plotted a histogram but the default scales are way to big (increments of 2), which made my data look right skewed. How do I change the increments of my histogram x axis to better fit my data?
This is my current histogram code:

```
hist(pvalues)
```

Comment: You could try changing the `breaks` value: `hist(pvalues, breaks = 20)`

Comment: If you are talking about just the x-axis ticks/labels, then try using `hist(..., axes=FALSE)` and then [`axis(1, ...)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.1/topics/axis).